# Read Input In An Array, Store -1 Value, And Exit When -1 Is Entered?

Tags: c, arrays, debugging, switch-statement, computer-science

I am trying to make a program that first prompts the user with a menu with menu options starting from 0 to 7.

I have a switch statement to check for what numbers are entered. This program is not finished I am starting on the "build list option" where I was the user to enter value to have it stored into an array, when the user enters a "-1" I want it to store the -1 in the array as well store the numbers the user entered.

The problem is: the program does not keep prompting the user to enter a number until a '-1' is entered. Instead it will display the next menu option and exits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 50

void main ()
{   
    int i = 0;
    int userinput[SIZE];
    int x = 0;

    do
    {
        printf("===DSCI0====\n");
        printf("0. Build List\n");
        printf("1. Display List Forward\n");
        printf("2. Display List Backwards\n");
        printf("3. Insert into list\n");
        printf("4. Append into list\n");
        printf("5. Obtain from List\n");
        printf("6. Clear List\n");
        printf("7. Quit\n");
        printf("What is your menu option?\n");
        scanf("%d", &i);

   } while(i < 0 || i > 7);

   switch(i)
   {
       case(0) : 
               for (x = 0; x < SIZE; x++);
               {
                  printf("Enter a value for ther array (-1 to quit): \n");
                  scanf("%x", &userinput[x]);
                  if(userinput[x] == -1)
                  {
                       break;
                  }
    }       

       case(1) : printf("Display List Fwd\n");
                        break;
       case(2) : printf("Display List Bkwd\n");
                        break;
        case(3) : printf("Insert into list\n");
                        break;
        case(4) : printf("Append into list\n");
                        break;
        case(5) : printf("Obtain from list\n");
                        break;
        case(6) : printf("Clear List\n");
                        break;
        case(7) : printf("Good-Bye\n");
                        exit(0);    
                        break;
        default : printf("Enter a value 0-7\n");
                        exit(0);
                        break;
   }

}
```

Update:

The solution I was given helped me with entering digits into my array. However when I try to read it out I am not getting the inputted values.

```
switch(i)
{
   case(0) : 
           for (x = 0; x < SIZE; x++)
           {
              printf("Enter a value for ther array (-1 to quit): \n");
              scanf("%x", &userinput[x]);
              if(userinput[x] == -1)
              {
                   break;
              }
}       

   case(1) : 
            for (x = 0; x < SIZE; x++)
            {
                printf("[%i.] %i\n", i + 1, &userinput[x]);
                if(userinput[x] == -1)
                {
                      break;
                }
```

My output in this example is:

```
What is your menu option?
0
Enter a value for the array (-1 to quit):
0
Enter a value for the array (-1 to quit):
1
Enter a value for the array (-1 to quit):
2
Enter a value for the array (-1 to quit):
3
Enter a value for the array (-1 to quit):
-1

 1. 698667216
 1. 698667216
 1. 698667216
 1. 698667216
 Display List Bkwd
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the last semicolon in

```
for (x = 0; x < SIZE; x++);
```

in order to put the block after the loop inside the loop and have the system iterate the block.

Then, add `break;` after the block to iterate in order not to let the system proceed to display the next menu.

Also note that you should use standard `int main(void)` in hosted environment instead of `void main()`, which is illegal in C89 and implementation-defined in C99 or later, unless you have some special reason to use non-standard signature.

To answer updated question:

```
printf("[%i.] %i\n", i + 1, &userinput[x]);
```

will invoke *undefined behavior* because data having wrong type is passed to `printf()`: `%i` calls for `int`, but `&userinput[x]` is type `int*`. Use `userinput[x]` without `&` to print the contents of the array.

Comment: Thank you, I got that part to work perfectly! However, I encountered a bug while trying to print out the array contents